# using low variable as parameter in exp:channel:entries

Tags: low-variables

I'm having an issue I can't get around (even not after reading [Low variable as channel entry_id parameter across MSM sites](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19490/low-variable-as-channel-entry-id-parameter-across-msm-sites) that looks a similar problem)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="references" limit="5" 
sort="desc" category="{embed:cats}" entry_id="NOT {exp:low_variables:single 
var='elv_excluded_entry_ids' preparse:target_channel='references' 
preparse:from_subsite='innoviso' }" }
```

I'm trying to exclude certain entries to be shown based on some logic build in a low variable

```
{if from_subsite=="innoviso"}
{exp:dandy_cat:entries channel="{target_channel}" category="(17)&(not 16)"}
{entry_id}|
{/exp:dandy_cat:entries}
{/if}
{if from_subsite=="solutions"}
{exp:dandy_cat:entries channel="{target_channel}" category="(16)&(not 17)"}
{entry_id}|
{/exp:dandy_cat:entries}
{/if}
```

I've made generic so it can be reused on different parts of the site.  When outputting the low variable in a template I get an list of entry_ids as expected.

When I do the same in the exp:channel:entries tag i get something like this

entry_id="NOT M00o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr"

I've tried the solution mentioned in the other post, but that does not work for me unfortunately.  Any ideas anyone?

rg,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you linked is a Select variable type, which stores its value as a pipe-separated list of items. You can use that as a parameter value.

Your variable, on the other hand, **contains conditionals and tags**. These are **not** parsed before they hit the template, but are put in the template and are **then** parsed **by the template**.

You're thinking the exp-tags and conditionals are evaluated **before** they hit the actual template, but that is **not** the case.

LV will put its content into the template, like Snippets. What you need, is an early parsed LV in variable syntax (ie. `{lv_my_var}`) which contains **the entry IDs themselves, *not* the logic to generate those IDs**. If you do need the latter, you'd need to create your own add-on that returns those IDs.

PS, I'll just leave this here: http://gotolow.com/parse-order